# What is wrong with this code (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) return){

}
```

Parsing error : Unexpected Token return

Comment: You have a `return` inside an `if` statement..  you want it after the `{`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `return` statement has to be in the *body of the `if`*, not as part of the condition. (Voting to close as off-topic due to typo).

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
    return;
}
```

Your `return` was misplaced.